# How to retrieve the struts2 action class paramater value in html meta tag?

Tags: jsp, struts2, meta-tags

I would like to know how to retrieve the Struts2 action class parameter value in meta tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="2; url='?'"/>

<body onload="redirectToURL();">
<s:hidden id="redirectURL" name="redirectURL" value="%{redirect}" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`property` tag](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/property) is not UI tag and it writes to the response out.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="2; url='<s:property value="%{redirect}"/>'"/>
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked . But , original request url gets appended to redirect url when redirect happens . As a result , it displays empty page.http://localhost:8080/<originalrequest>/<redirecturl>.                                        Also, redirect url contains encoded characters like  %3A%2F etc ..                     redirect url - http%3A%2F%2Fabc-www.website.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fget%2Ftime

Comment: The browser should be able to decode characters that were urlencoded. I can't guess what remains original request without code. BTW, you should upvote answer that helped you.